# Check for a change in variable value in forreach loop

Tags: php, loops, foreach

So I have a checkbox that sends to a PHP script. Basically, my checkboxes create an array, of course. Seeing it's one of those `$var[]` ones.

So basically, my array will look like this in code:

```
$vars = array('12345:0','45678:0','78910:0','3434:1','2345:1');

foreach ($vars as $var) {
    $vinfo = explode(":", $var);
    $vgroup = $vinfo[0];
    $vacct = $vinfo[1];

    // Various function calls with those variables. 
}
```

Now, as you can see. I am splitting for vinfo and vaccount. In my source. I have two accounts (in this example). Some groups belong to 0 and some groups belong to 1. I want to run the function `switchAccount("details");` whenever there's a change in the `$vacct` variable in the foreach loop. In this case, it should only switch once (seeing 0 is default).

"Account" (`$vacct`) switches vary based on the user input in the checkbox. But (usually) always goes up one number. Again, depending on admin input.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try this

```
$vars = array('12345:0','45678:0','78910:0','3434:1','2345:1');
$vacct = '';
foreach ($vars as $var)
{
    $vinfo = explode(":", $var);
    $vgroup = $vinfo[0];

    if($vacct != $vinfo[1])
    {
        switchAccount("details");
        $vacct = $vinfo[1];

    }
}
```

Comment: That works if the only variables are either 0 or 1. Sometimes they go as high as 100. I just put a limited number of them. But yeah, that will work if switching from 0 to another value. But the switching can happen more than that. It can switch from 1 for a while, then 2 for a while longer ,etc.

Comment: @user1687621 `$vacct` gets updated with the new number when it's no longer equal to the current one, so it should keep going past 0 and 1. Have you tried it?

Comment: Yes, @Bono Completely agree with you.

Comment: @user1687621 It always update $vacct, whenever it found that the previous value inside $vacct is not equal to the current value (which is $vinfo[1]).

Comment: @AnkurTiwari Yeah I've tested both your and my own answer, both work perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

I've replaced your `foreach` for a normal `for` so you can get the information of the "previous" iteration. This way you can check if there has been a change in `$vacct`.

```
for($i = 0; $i < count($vars); $i++){
    $vinfo = explode(":", $vars[$i]);
    $vgroup = $vinfo[0];
    $vacct = $vinfo[1];

    if($i > 0){ //Make sure we don't get a -1 index
        $previous = $vars[$i - 1]; //Get previous info
        $previous_info = explode(':', $previous);
        $previous_vacct = $previous_info[1];

        if($previous_vacct != $vacct){
            //Do switching function
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: THat code seems to be defective. As it tries to do the account switching even when the vacct variable doesn't even change.

Comment: @user1687621 have you tried running these code snippets? My code outputs (with an added `12356:3` in the `$vars` array) `1` & `3` once. @AnkurTiwari 's code outputs `0`, `1` & `3` once. So both answers here are tested and work. What exactly isn't working for you, because this should work.